# Nested if and is blank returning Parse Error

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula

I am returning an error on a nested if function checking a couple different parameters and performing a calculation. See screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJCGO.jpg)

I want an if statement to determine if F2 is blank, if it’s not then I want to perform a few checks and calcs based on H2’s value. Either Y, N, or NA. The formula reads correctly in my head but it’s returning an error.

If H2 is Y then calc G2-F2 and return that value,
Else If H2 is N then calc F2*(-1) or just the neg. Of F2,
Else if H2 is NA then just return F2,
Else if H2 is none of the above return 0

Where have I gone wrong? Or is there a more elegant/simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

You
Just have 1 more closing parenthesis than you need. **Try removing the last `)` and your formula should work**:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F2),0,
  IF(H2="Y",G2-F2,
    IF(H2="N",F2*(-1),
      IF(H2="NA",F2,
        0
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: @SheetHelp any luck trying this solution?